# What's wrong with following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a SQL server db, when I execute following query I get 4 results:

```
WITH MyCTE (ID, hasLead, SubgroupFk, SubTeamFk)
AS (
SELECT [ID],[hasLead],[SubgroupFk],[SubTeamFk]
FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[LinkProject-Area]
where [ProjectFk]=90
)
SELECT 
*
FROM MyCTE 
INNER JOIN EmplTeam ON EmplTeam.ID = MyCTE.SubTeamFk 
INNER JOIN [Department] ON [Department].ID = MyCTE.SubgroupFk
```

For every LinkProjectArea Id I have 1 Headcount item / year
Headcount table is connected with: LinkProjectAreaFk to previous mentioned table

So I thought I can combine the headcount with following query:

```
WITH MyCTE (ID, hasLead, SubgroupFk, SubTeamFk)
AS (
SELECT [ID],[hasLead],[SubgroupFk],[SubTeamFk]
FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[LinkProject-Area]
where [ProjectFk]=90
)
SELECT 
*
FROM MyCTE 
INNER JOIN EmplTeam ON EmplTeam.ID = MyCTE.SubTeamFk 
INNER JOIN [Department] ON [Department].ID = MyCTE.SubgroupFk 
INNER JOIN [HeadCount] ON [HeadCount].LinkProjectAreaFk = MyCTE.ID
```

But when I execute this query I get no results but every id of this query has a headcount. What am I doing wrong?
I really have no clue

Comment: may be data could help us to help you...

Comment: Did you try a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN by HeadCount, with that you can see the 4 results and you can check for sure, is there a connection or not

Comment: When I use Left Join all the data comming from the HC table = NULL but the results of the ID's from the first query are : 97,98,99,100 and when I execute  this query: Select * from HC where ID=97 or ID=98 or ID=99 or ID=100 I do get 4 results

Comment: It means, there is no connection on those ids

Comment: And what are the values of `HeadCount.LinkProjectAreaFk` when doing `select LinkProjectAreaFk from HeadCount`?

Comment: When executing this query I get : SELECT [LinkProjectAreaFk] FROM [LocalGTPDatabase].[dbo].[HeadCount] WHERE [HcYear]='2012' and ([LinkProjectAreaFk]=97 or [LinkProjectAreaFk]=99 or [LinkProjectAreaFk]= 100 or [LinkProjectAreaFk]=98 ) result is [LinkProjectAreaFk] are 97,98,99,100

Comment: @user1514838: Impossible. Please check again which column we are talking about here. In your last comment you said the same but with the *ID* column! Please get your facts right before posting here.

Comment: I want it to be impossible but these are the results I get and it drives me insane because I don't see what I do wrong
LinkProjectArea has an ID and Headcount has a foreign key [LinkProjectAreaFk]

Comment: You are mixing columns here. It is impossible to answer your question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get no error but just no data, there is probably no data.
Maybe if there is a "HeadCount"Item, there is no Department-Item or there is no Empl-Team-Item that fits.

Basically you have an and-Connection. Show all combinations of MyCTE, EmplTeam, Department and HeadCount, where ALL of your three "ON-Conditions" are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on the wrong column!

You need to also use the ID column on the HeadCount table:

```
INNER JOIN [HeadCount] ON [HeadCount].ID = MyCTE.ID
```

---

This answer is based on your comment:

> Select * from HC where **ID**=97 or **ID**=98 or **ID**=99 or **ID**=100 I do get 4 results

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query to be sure, is the FK reference exists on those IDs or not:

```
SELECT *
FROM HeadCount
WHERE HeadCount.LinkProjectAreaFk IN
(SELECT [ID]
FROM [LinkProject-Area]
where [ProjectFk]=90)
```

IF it has nothing to return it means, that those IDs are not existing as a Forign Key in HeadCount